# associate pandas dataframe with postgres table

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, git, sqlalchemy

The application I am building is about analyzing git logs and pull requests for particular project's repo. A user can have multiple projects and each project can have multiple repos on which analysis will be done. Up to now what I have done is, I have created a table for user, projects and repo. Regarding repo analysis to calculate various metrics, I have done created a separate package where it fetches logs for the selected repo and then parsed that logs to csv format for further calculation of metrics like coding days, churn, number of authors, commit list, commit count with each commit size and so on. Now that I need to integrate that package with api, I can only think of associating the dataframe that package generates with a specific repo. But I don't know how I can do this and also not sure if this is the good approach.

I am using fastapi and sqlalchemy with postgres as a database

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    full_name = Column(String, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean(), default=False)
    projects = relationship("Project", back_populates="owner")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<User {self.id} {self.email}>"

class Project(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="projects")
    name = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    description = Column(Text)
    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    repositories = relationship("Repository", back_populates="project")
    created_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<Project {self.id} {self.name}>"


class Repository(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("project.id"))
    project = relationship("Project", back_populates="repositories")
    name = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    created_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<Repository {self.id} {self.name}>"
```

Now for the repo analysis which is completely a separate package where its been coded in this way

main.py

```
def parser(commit_log):
    commits = pd.read_csv(commit_log, sep="\u0012", header=None, names=["raw"])
    commit_marker = commits[commits["raw"].str.startswith("--", na=False)]
    commit_info = commit_marker["raw"].str.extract(
        r"^--(?P<SHA>.*?)--(?P<Timestamp>.*?)--(?P<Author>.*?)$", expand=True
    )
    file_stats_marker = commits[~commits.index.isin(commit_info.index)]
    file_stats = file_stats_marker["raw"].str.split("\t", expand=True)
    file_stats = file_stats.rename(
        columns={0: "Insertion", 1: "Deletion", 2: "File path"}
    )
    file_stats["Insertion"] = pd.to_numeric(
        file_stats["Insertion"], errors="coerce"
    )
    file_stats["Deletion"] = pd.to_numeric(file_stats["Deletion"], errors="coerce")

    commit_data = commit_info.reindex(commits.index).fillna(
        method="ffill"
    ) 
    commit_data = commit_data[~commit_data.index.isin(commit_info.index)]
    commit_data = commit_data.join(file_stats)
    return commit_data


class CommitAnalyzer(object):
    def __init__(self, commit_log) -> None:
        self.commit_df = parser(commit_log)
        def total_commit_counts(self):
        return self.commit_df["SHA"].nunique()

    def list_all_authors(self):
        return pd.unique(self.commit_df["Author"])

    def total_authors(self):
        len(pd.unique(self.commit_df["Author"]))

    def top_authors(self, topby=10):
        topauthors = (
            self.commit_df.groupby(by=["Author"])["SHA"].nunique().nlargest(topby)
        )
        return topauthors

    def total_commits_by_author(self, author):
        commits = (
            self.commit_df[self.commit_df["Author"] == author]
            .groupby(by=["Author"])["SHA"]
            .nunique()
        )
        return commits

if __name__ == "__main__":
    analyzer = CommitAnalyzer(COMMIT_LOG)
```

the csv that is generated looks like following

[image]

How can I associate the package which generates various metrics for a repo so I can send metrics of that repo in an api?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Can you explain your question a bit more? That's a lot of code and very little. You have written a package that creates a dataframe that you export as a csv. And now? You want to provide those results through an API?

Comment: please clarify your question - what *exactly* do you need help with?

Comment: There is a package which fetches git logs data and parse it as a csv which then calculates all the metrics. I want to now provide those metrics result through an api. For this use case, I am not sure how I can connect this to my api server. Connect api server with my package whose task is to only calculate the metrics.